# Updating rsync through Homebrew vs updating through .tar download

Tags: rsync, tar

What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of updating the version of rsync installed using Homebrew vs downloading a .tar file and installing it this way https://hargitai.co.nz/upgrade-rsync-on-mac-os-x/

Is what's offered through/from(?) Samba, Github ( https://github.com/rsyncOSX ), and Homebrew (I saw one page describing it as a package manager) all the same program?  Or is there some difference (maybe some are forks of others, for example)?

What is Samba from the perspective of a personal computer running OSX?

Answer (score 2):

When you install `rsync` through HomeBrew an additional patch with a bugfix is applied to the code before it is compiled and installed on your system. You will not (automatically) get this patch when installing manually from a .tar.gz.

HomeBrew also ensures to install dependencies easily. You will have to do that manually when doing it yourself.

Finally HomeBrew makes it easier to uninstall `rsync` again, if you do not need it anymore.

The software offered on rsync.samba.org and installed in the guide you link is almost identical to the software installed through HomeBrew, except for the extra patch I mentioned.

The software on GitHub you link to is actually not `rsync`. It is a graphical user interface for `rsync`, that requires you to have `rsync` installed in advance.

Regarding Samba: `rsync` as such does not have anything to do with the software package named "Samba" - so there's no "Samba" involved in running `rsync` on your personal computer.

The reason why the `rsync` program is offered through a web site hosted on samba.org is probably just that one of the original creators of the `rsync` program (Andrew Tridgell) also happens to be original creator of the Samba software package.